# The padding style applying to <img> in IE7 is separate from FF3?

Tags: html, css

I got a image like below with padding-right: 15px

```
<td><img style="padding:0px 15px 0px 0px;..." />
<td><td>another image<td/>
```

But the effect shows on IE and FF is a bit different. Is the way to measure is separate?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you miss out the quote for the style attribute? `<img style="padding:0px 15px 0px 0px;..." />`

Comment: I edited it. The result still remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your HTML is absolutely invalid and horrible. Change it to:

```
<td><img style="padding: 0px 15px 0px 0px;" /></td>
<td>another image</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

It’s hard to tell without seeing your full HTML / CSS, but perhaps this is a `line-height` issue?

Images are inline elements by default, which means they get a `line-height` applied to them. This might cause extra ‘margin’ at the bottom.

Try applying `display: block;` to the `img` element, like so:

```
<td><img style="padding: 0 15px 0; display: block;" alt="" /></td>
<td>Another image</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the display of the `<img>` by adding this to your css file:

```
DIV-Name img{ display:block;} /* display:block to support with IE7 */
```